# Insert 2 select in same insert SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, unpivot, lateral-join

i have a problem, i would like use  2 select to insert in new table but i don't know if it's possible...

my code :

```
insert INTO attributs_libres_lignes VALUES  ( SELECT LIGN_PKID, "INSERT HERE" from ATTRIBUTS_LIGNES a, "HERE THE NUMBER OF COLUMN OF PKID (1 to 4)", "HERE A DATE");
```

```
select COLONNE01 from attributs_lignes
union all select COLONNE02 from attributs_lignes
union all select COLONNE03 from attributs_lignes
union all select COLONNE04 from attributs_lignes
```

I would like insert the second part ( select COLONNE01....) in the first part instead of "INSERT HERE"

DATA OLD TABLE : COLUMNS 1 ("PKID1", one","two","three")
COLUMNS 2 ("PKID2","one","two", "three")

New TABLE :

(PKID1, one, 1)
(PKID2, one, 1)
(PKID1, two, 2)
(PKID2, two, 2)
(PKID1, three, 3)
(PKID2, three, 3)

-

Comment: insert into t2 (c1, c2) select ca, cb from ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't that just as simple as this?

```
insert into attributs_libres_lignes
select lign_pkid, colonne01 from attributs_lignes union all
select lign_pkid, colonne02 from attributs_lignes union all
select lign_pkid, colonne03 from attributs_lignes union all
select lign_pkid, colonne04 from attributs_lignes;
```

Comment: It's that ! but now i would like add a new columns which contains a number according to the PKID, if it is the first column of PKID 1 on met 1, if it is the second column of PKID 1 one puts 2 and so on

Comment: but it's not a recovery from the old table so I'm stuck

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Please, edit the question you posted and add sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CROSS JOIN as follows:

```
INSERT INTO ATTRIBUTS_LIBRES_LIGNES
SELECT A.LIGN_PKID,
       C.COL_ATTRIBUTES
  FROM ATTRIBUTS_LIGNES A
 CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COLONNE01 COL_ATTRIBUTES FROM ATTRIBUTS_LIGNES UNION ALL
    SELECT COLONNE02 FROM ATTRIBUTS_LIGNES UNION ALL
    SELECT COLONNE03 FROM ATTRIBUTS_LIGNES UNION ALL
    SELECT COLONNE04 FROM ATTRIBUTS_LIGNES
) C
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `cross apply` to unpivot. This is more efficient than `union`, because it scans the table only once, instead of once per member subquery.

So:

```
insert into attributs_libres_lignes (lign_pkid, colonne)
select a.lign_pkid, v.colonne
from attributs_lignes a
cross apply (
    select a.colonne01 colonnefrom dual
    union all select a.colonne02 from dual
    union all select a.colonne03 from dual
    union all select a.colonne04 from dual
) v
```

Note that it is a good practice to enumerate the target columns of the `insert` statement. I assumed that the columns of the target table are `lign_pkid` and `colonne`, you might need to review that.